# PHP MySQL curdate()

Tags: php, mysql, date

In MySQL, I can use:

```
 SELECT * FROM container WHERE containerDate = CURDATE() + 1;
```

That returns everything where the containerDate is within 24 hours of the current date.

But now, I need to put that into PHP.

I have a PHP variable called $next_day.  How can I get CURDATE() + 1 into the variable so that the query runs in PHP like how it does in MySQL?

In the form, I tried to set the value of the GET to "CURDATE() + 1", but that reads in as a string, and therefore, PHP reads the value with single quotes, IE: 'CURDATE() + 1'

Is there even a way to set the variable $next_day to CURDATE() + 1 ?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('+1 day');
```

With first command you obtain today date, with second, you modify it adding one day (tomorrow date)

Try it yourself: [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p94-856)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the MySQL function ADDDATE, and select that:

```
    SELECT ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 1);
```

This will give you a correct date, if you use CURDATE()+1, it seems to fail if the month days are exceeded. 
It seems a better idea to use the suggested answers to get the time directly from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

will give you a unix timestamp, which is DIRECTLY usable by the PHP time system. Best to use the MySQL date, because it's possible for your query to run at 11:59:59.999pm, and PHP to generate its own date at 12:00:00.0001 am the next day.

Answer (score 0):

```
$next_day = strtotime('+1 day');
```

Pretty easy. @DonCallisto s solution is also correct.